# QObject destructors not being called

Tags: qt, memory-management, destructor, qobject

I have two `QObject` child classes in my Qt application. One object from each of these classes was instantiated on the stack. Previously, my application would exit cleanly. However, since I've updated to Qt5.1.0, their destructors are not being called. I get the following warning twice when I launch the debugger.

```
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//lib64/libfreebl3.so.debug" 
does not match "/lib64/libfreebl3.so" (CRC mismatch)
```

Is this a bug in Qt or in my code?

Comment: The given warning seems more like two different versions of the same library installed

Comment: Please show how do you create objects. The error message seems to be unrelated to the issue.

Comment: @Riateche They were created in the main function on the stack (not dynamically allocated).

Comment: @SebastianLange Actually, I do have two versions of `libfreebl3.so`. One is in located in `/lib64` and the other in `/usr/lib64`. They do not match the other.

Comment: How do you stop the application? May be it is crashed, not exited normally. Do you specify `parent` object for those objects?

Comment: @Riateche This application is multithreaded. It exits when you close the window. The extra threads are killed in the destructors of the objects that launched the threads. These objects don't have parents. The destructors are supposedly to be by called once we leave the main function. However, the destructors are never called and the extra threads continue running and printing their results.

Comment: I'm aware this is an old question but I just got this situation in a single threaded application. I can solve it by giving the QObject a parent. Failing to do so, it would not get destructed even if in a unique_pointer or created with automatic storage. 
I wonder if Qt simply moves elements under the hood. Still, even in that case, I can't begin to understand why it doesn't get destructed even upon cleanly exiting a single threaded app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation of `QCoreApplication::exec`:

> We recommend that you connect clean-up code to the aboutToQuit() signal, instead of putting it in your application's main() function because on some platforms the QCoreApplication::exec() call may not return. For example, on Windows when the user logs off, the system terminates the process after Qt closes all top-level windows. Hence, there is no guarantee that the application will have time to exit its event loop and execute code at the end of the main() function after the QCoreApplication::exec() call.

You're using it incorrectly. It is not guaranteed that `exec` will be terminated after windows are closed. You should use `aboutToQuit` signal to stop other threads. If this signal is not emitted either, you need to call `QApplication::quit()` explicitly when your window is closed.

Comment: `exec` does return though. The QObjects which are not being deleted are causing the process to not exit because these QObjects are being used to launch seperate threads, which don't get killed until the destuctor is called.

Comment: Just tested my application on different machine. It seems that I didn't implement a good destructor on one of my QObjects. It would hang waiting for a thread to join back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure in this case if this is a bug in your code or not, but anyway it is *not recommended* to create `QObject`s in the stack.

The reason is that the parent object (if any) will automatically call `delete` when destroyed, but then the object will also be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. Hence the object is destroyed twice which is *Undefined Behaviour*. That may explained why it worked well in one case, and not in another, since you can't rely on any consistent behaviour.

(But in your case it is weird that you say the destructor is *not called* at all...)